# Move caption to the center of the figure

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to put the caption of each subfigure in the center of the subfigure but it appears to the left. Do you know how can I move the caption of the subfigures and also the caption of the Figure? Thanks in advanced!

```
    \begin{figure}[h]

\centering

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{Non-State.png}

  \caption{Non-State Violence}

  \label{fig:sub1}

\end{subfigure}%

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{One-Sided.png}

  \caption{One Sided violence}

  \label{fig:sub2}

\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}

  \centering

  \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{State-Based.png}

  \caption{State-Based Violence}

  \label{fig:sub3}

\end{subfigure}

\caption{Type of Violence}

\label{fig:test}

\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your code produces two, not three, subfigures. Moreover, the subfigures are necessarily placed below each other and centered. Please clarify.

Comment: You are completely right. I put another code, I am sorry. What I want is to put the subtitle of each figure just down of each subfigure, not to the left of the subfigure.

Comment: With the information you provided so far, I can not reproduce the output you get. If I take your code fragment and turn it into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), the captions are centered with respect to the individual images. I can only reproduce the output you get, if I add `\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}` to the preamble of my MWE. Could it be possible, that thouse two lineas are also present in your document. If so, try removing the `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false}`.

Comment: For me, the code works. I have added \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} and now I obtain the result I want. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: The main point that @leandriis was making is that the code you posted automatically centers single-line subcaptions. There's *no need* for the `justification=centering` option unless the captions' widths exceed that of the underlying `subfigure` environments. But, elsewhere, you've indicated that that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  %\centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.42\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graph1.png}
    \caption{"Stable" Countries group}
    \label{fig:sub1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{.42\textwidth}
    %\centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graph2.png}
    \caption{"unstable" Countries group}
    \label{fig:sub2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Number of Actors by Year and Countries}
  \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:** I took Mico's advice so long captions align better with the graphic.

Comment: Did you try to compile this code? AFAICT, it doesn't load a package that defines `\includegraphics`. Please clarify.

Comment: It works with \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}. Thank you!

Comment: Oops, that is right, I added the missing package.

Comment: With this setup, captions that take up multiple lines will also be horizontally centered.

Comment: This approach lets the width of the longer subcaptions *exceed* that of the associated graphs. Probably not a good outcome. Better to set `\begin{subfigure}{.0.42\textwidth}` (b/c 0.6*0.7=0.42) and `[width=\linewidth]`. That way, the captions' widths can be no greater than that of the graphs.

Comment: This code also produces a `figure` environment whose overall width equals `1.2\textwidth` and the second graph protruding noticeably in the right-hand margin. I'd like to suggest you change both instances of `\begin{subfigure}{.6\textwidth}` to `\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}` in order to avoid this problem.

Comment: +1 for the edits. I've taken the liberty of editing your code some more in order to provide some horizontal separation between the subfigures. Feel free to revert.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think to achieve your formatting objective is to change `[width=.6\linewidth]` to `[width=\linewidth]` and, if necessary, to change the widths of the `subfigure` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graph1.png}
\caption{Non-state violence}
\label{fig:sub1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graph2.png}
\caption{One-sided violence}
\label{fig:sub2}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Graph3.png}
\caption{State-based violence}
\label{fig:sub3}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Types of violence}
\label{fig:test}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What I have done is what was suggested by ttnick: write \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} and it works. Thank you again for the answer. I will keep it!

Comment: @OgeiD - I guess it depends on how one defines "it works". If letting the widths of longer captions exceed that of the associated graphs can be called "it works", I suppose you're right.

Comment: Hahaha, good comment. Probably, you are right. For me,  It works means that it solves what I wanted to do with that figure. Maybe in other cases it will not be a solution.

Comment: @Zarko - Many thanks. I've only just now noticed that there was an issue in the opening sentence. Hopefully, that's now fixed.